# Python Appengine Mapreduce gives Bad Entity Kind on run

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I've been struggling with this for hours...

In my project, I have my models.py defined in folder "project", under the main root.  I also have the mapreduce files in folder "mapreduce", inside the "project" folder.  Files system looks like:

Main Root
-Project folder
-> models.py
    -> Mapreduce folder

I have the mapreduce.yaml file defined as:

```
mapreduce:
- name: Advice_Hidden
  mapper:
    input_reader: mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader
    handler: mapreduce.main_map_handler.add_hidden
    params:
    - name: entity_kind
      default: project.models.Advice
```

But when I try to run mapreduce, I get the error:

```
BadReaderParamsError: Bad entity kind: Could not find 'models' on path 'advice'
```

Can anyone help me out?  Should also note that I'm using Django-Piston as well.

Comment: Where is your app.yaml? In 'Main root' or 'project folder'? If the former, does your project folder have a `__init__.py`?

Comment: my app.yaml is in the main root along with the mapreduce.yaml.  Yes, my Project folder has a __init__.py as well.  Do you think it could be my file structure?  I tried having the mapreduce folder under the root as well but to no avail.

Comment: It looks like you're running into a problem with how mapreduce imports modules. Try rearranging your imports so `models.py` is under the top-level. If that solves it, you should file a bug with the mapreduce project. Also, you shouldn't be modifying the mapreduce package - put the handler in your own package.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, re-arranging works, but I can't now rearrange my folder structure. In my case, I have a **_*init*_**.py under the "projects" directory. Also tried to add a **_*init*_**.py under the root directory where app.yaml and mapreduce.yaml reside (to no avail)

Strangely, my error is different. Using your example, it would be

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/input_readers.py", line 660, in validate
    raise BadReaderParamsError("Bad entity kind: %s" % e)
BadReaderParamsError: Bad entity kind: **Could not find 'models' on path 'project'**
```

Actually, just found out that in production it works, that is, the root directory (where app .yaml resides) is in sys.path. In the sdk it isn't. Need to find out why. Investigating.